# Inequalities and their solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

a. Since: $9|x + 9| + 6 > 5$

$9|x + 9| > -1 $

$|x + 9| > -\frac19$

which is true for every real $x$ value, so it has infinitely many solutions.

$(−\infty, \infty)$

How would I graph this solution set on a number line?

b. Fill in the blanks
$−6 < 4 − 2x ≤ −5 $

====================

$?\  <\  ?x\  ≤\  ?$

$?\  >\  x\  ≥ \ ?$

$?\  ≤ \ x\  <\  ?$

I got $[\frac92,-5)$ for the answer but I do not know what to fill in for these blanks.

---

Couldn't post the sequence in the right format so here it is:

$-6<4-2x≤-5$

$-10<-2x≤-9$

$5>x≥ \frac92$

$\frac92≤x<5$

Is this correct? 
And if so, why do the signs at the end change from: $>,≥$ to $≤,<$?
I must have missed a rule or something....

Comment: **a.** Just draw the real line since $(−\infty,\infty)=\Bbb R$. **b.** That you fill in the blanks is just another way of saying to solve the inequality for $x$.

Comment: For b, your answer is not correct. maybe a typo?

Answer (score 2):

For (a), the solution set $(-\infty, +\infty)$ can be graphed simply as the the entire real number line. Just draw the number line in bold, if you must graph it, or better yet, draw the number line as you normally would, and use, say, red, to cover the entire number line (or outline the number line in red.)

$$(b) \quad \begin{align} −6 < 4 − 2x ≤ −5 & \iff -10 < -2x \lt -9\tag{1}\\ \\
& \iff 5 > x \geq 4.5\tag{2}\end{align}$$

Equivalently, $4.5\leq x \lt 5$. I.e., the solution set is given by $[4.5, 5)$.

*Note that when I divided the chain of inequalities by $-2$ (line (1) to line (2)), I needed to reverse the direction of the inequalities. Remember that multiplying or dividing by a negative value reverses the direction of the inequality.

Comment: So would this be the correct sequence?

-6<4-2x≤-5
-10<-2x≤-9

5>x≥9/2

9/2≤x<5

and if so why do the signs at the end change from: >,≥ to ≤,<
I must have missed a rule or something...

Comment: See my note at the end of my post: When dividing or multiplying an inequality by a negative number, the direction of the inequality reverses. In my work above, in the last step, I divided through by $-2$, which reverses the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have read that over!

Comment: Is what I have correct?

Comment: You're welcome, Jimmie. Yes, Jimmie. It is exactly what I posted in my answer. $\frac 92 = 4.5$. Use whichever you prefer.

Comment: We can write the solution in one of two ways: $5>x\geq \frac 92$ is one way, but I prefer $ \frac 92 \leq x \lt 5$, or simply $x \in \left[\frac 92, 5\right)$.